# Convert hive console output to text or csv

Tags: unix, hive, console

I need to perform a count on Hive table and output the result into a text file and drop it at another location as a trigger.

The hive output currently looks like this:

```
+-------------+----------+
|     _c0     |   _c1    |
+-------------+----------+
| 2020-03-01  | 3203500  |
+-------------+----------+
```

I tried options like following:

```
hive -e 'select CURRENT_DATE, count(*) from db.table;' | sed 's/[[:space:]]\+/,/g' > /trigger/trigger_file.txt
```

But its not giving the expected the result. What else can i try?

The expected outcome inside the .txt file is as follows:

```
2020-03-01,3203500
```

Comment: Try replacing `sed` command with `awk -F'[| ]+' '$2 ~ /[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}/{print $2","$3}'`

Comment: This worked perfectly just like a charm. I guess i have to step up my game with regex. Thank you So much Wiktor.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please consider accepting [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60497631/3832970)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may replace your sed command with

```
awk -F'[| ]+' '$2 ~ /[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}/{print $2","$3}'
```

The `-F'[| ]+'` sets the field separator to a `[| ]+` regex that matches one or more occurrences of a space or pipe chars, then grabs all records where the second field matches a datelike pattern (`[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/lRDTHn/1)), and prints their second and third column values with a comma and space in between.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid all replacing results using sed ..etc, try with this approach using [**`concat_ws(',',col1,col2...etc)`**](https://www.folkstalk.com/2011/11/string-functions-in-hive.html) and results output will have `,` separated data!

```
hive -e 'select CONCAT_WS(',',CURRENT_DATE, count(*)) from Mytable' > /home/user/Mycsv.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

Hive provides inbuilt command to write into files

```
INSERT OVERWRITE LOCAL DIRECTORY '/home/docs/temp' ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' select * from db.table;
```

Other way

```
hive -S -e 'set hive.cli.print.header=false; select * from db.table' | sed 's/[[:space:]]\+/,/g' > /home/docs/temp.csv
```